# What does Hinduism say about twin birth?

Tags: scripture, philosophy

In Puranas, there is a mention of Yama and Yami, who were twins. What does Hindu philosophy/scriptures say about twin(or triplet, quadruplet, e.t.c,) births for humans?

Comment: You mean how they are born?

Comment: @Sinister Yes, also about their soul, any connection past life, or anything related to them.

Answer (score 4):

[Garbha Upanishat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbha_Upanishad) gives a reason for birth of twins.

> vyākulitamanaso'ndhāḥ khañjāḥ kubjā vāmanā bhavanti
>   anyonya vāyuparipīḍita śukradvaidhyādvidhā tanuḥ syāttato yugmāḥ prajāyante
>
> If [at the time of impregnation] the parents are agitated, the child will be blind, crippled, hunch-backed or stunted. **If the vital air moves around, the seed enters in two parts, resulting in twins**.

Comment: Please can you tell the meaning of vital air?